# como restar una lista de python con los mismos valores de esa lista

Tags: python, odoo13

como puedo restar los valores de un mismo diccionario, el primer valor con el primero, el segundo con el primero, el tercero con el segundo y el 4to valor con el 3er valor.
aqui mi codigo:

```
        filas+=1
        vec=[]
        cont=0
        consulta_product= ("""
        SELECT display_name,date_order,price_unit FROM purchase_order_line pol
        join purchase_order po on po.id = pol.order_id
        join res_partner rp on po.partner_id = rp.id WHERE pol.product_id = """ + str(produ[1]) + """
        """)
        self.env.cr.execute(consulta_product)
        productoslinea = [j for j in self.env.cr.fetchall()]
        for vector in reversed(productoslinea):
            vec.append(vector[2])
        cont=len(vec)
            # cont=cont-1
        aux = 0
        for linea in productoslinea:
            aux+=1
            cont=cont-1
            contador=aux
            sheet.write('C'+str(filas+1), linea[0], letter4G)
            sheet.write('D'+str(filas+1), linea[1].strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S'), letter4G)
            sheet.write('E'+str(filas+1), linea[2], letter4G)
            sheet.write('F'+str(filas+1), vec[cont-1]-vec[contador], letter4G)
            filas+=1
```

el erro es que me dice que no existe el indice:

sheet.write('F'+str(filas+1), vec[cont-1]-vec[contador], letter4G)
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: ¿Restar valores de una misma lista o restar valores de un mismo diccionario? ¿sheet que es?¿un workbook de xlsxwriter?

Comment: Por favor explica mejor lo que quieres hacer, si puedes proporcionar un ejemplo mejor!

Comment: bueno @AnkiJedi te lo dejo, yo me largo a dormir

Comment: Jajajaa, que descanses bro

Comment: No hay diccionarios en el código, sino listas.